# Parsing JSON objects from .txt file

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I have a txt file that contains multiples Json objects (let say 10), I got this file through an http request. 
I'm trying on java to get all the Json objects (the 10 differents JSON objects)  contained in that file but I can't do it, as I don't know how to "separate" all the different Json objects. 
I'm using the Json simple library.

This is what I have now :

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("recordings.txt"); 
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(fr);
```

But this works only for one JSON object. Can you please help me ?

Edit: This is the query that gives the recordings.txt file :

[Query](https://www.xeno-canto.org/api/2/recordings?query=cnt:france)

The details of each JSON objects structure can be found here :

[JSON details](https://www.xeno-canto.org/article/153)

Comment: can please post the `recordings.txt` please ? we need a the structure of your JSON

Comment: You need to parse the file by yourself and separate it to individual objects.

Comment: Jackson's ObjecrReader has a readValues() method doing that.

Comment: Arthur, i edited my post with what you need

Comment: What exactly does your recordings.txt look like? If it looks exactly like the the result from your query: the result is just one big JSON object.

Comment: what is the delimiter between the JSON objects in the file?